# How do you remove last comma in a PHP for loop to build a JSON string

Tags: php, json, string, loops, for-loop

When building a JSON string from a php for loop from an SQL query there is an unnessary comma at the end of the build string. How do I control the final comma.

```
$count =  label::grabAll()->count();

echo '{"data": { "graph": {';

for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++){

if($x <= 3){
    $cm = ',';
}else{
    $cm .= '';
}

    echo '"'.$x.'": "'.label::grabAll()->results()[$x]->count.'"'.$cm;

}
```

I get this result from the code above.
[image]

How do I remove the final comma?

Comment: I recommend **not** building JSON strings by hand. Instead, populate an array and use `json_encode()`

Comment: what @Phil says. If you really want to concat data like that to s string rather use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with an array. (for any other usecase. just as a hint for the future)

Answer (score 1):

Use plain old objects / arrays and use `json_encode`. For example

```
$graph = array_map(function($result) {
    return $result->count;
}, label::graball()->results());

echo json_encode(['data' => ['graph' => $graph]]);
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/812302

Answer (score 0):

```
$count =  label::graball()->count();

$arr = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++){

 array_push($arr, label::graball()->results()[$x]->count);

}


echo json_encode($arr);
```

Thanks everyone for the quick responses. This works.

Comment: Are you sure that executing `label::graball()` and `label::graball()->results()` multiple times is the correct thing to do? Is each execution querying your data source?